# Prettier formatting configuration

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm pulling my hair trying to configure Prettier formatting for Angular HTML component. I tried different configuration overriding but I can't get what I want.

By default, on VS Code + Prettier, the following markup :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="emailRef.hasError('email')">A valid email address must be used</ng-container>
```

is formatted to (because of line length) :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="emailRef.hasError('email')"
  >A valid email address must be used</ng-container
>
```

which I don't like at all. I don't want Prettier to split the tag like that. I'd rather prefer :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="emailRef.hasError('email')">
  A valid email address must be used
</ng-container>
```

Does anyone knows how to override its default behavior ? I'm OK with the default formatting when multiple attributes are used, like in :

```
<input
  id="email"
  name="email"
  type="email"
  email
  required
  [(ngModel)]="email"
  #emailRef="ngModel"
/>
```

Comment: There’s a feature request for this in the works: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5377

Comment: Thanks Roy, I'll upvote it. So there's at the moment no solution unless the one specified by C_Ogoo bellow ?

Comment: Correct, not at this moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What works for me is to add a space between the content and the opening and closing tags:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="emailRef.hasError('email')"> A valid email address must be used </ng-container>
```

With the spaces, prettier formats it correctly

Comment: That's a nice trick. Seems to work too, but I'd rather a solution handled by Prettier.

Comment: I toiled for days trying to find a solution, one doesn't exist at the moment for prettier.

Comment: [Preetesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64329672/1028230) explains this behavior. If you have a block element, whitespace at the ends doesn't matter, and prettier makes things... um, prettier. If you have an inline element, like `span` or, here, assumedly `ng-container`, **whitespace can matter** -- `can<span>not</span>!` displays much differently than `can<span> not </span>!` But if you put in whitespace on both ends, now _any amount of whitespace is equivalent_ display-wise & prettier can default to its preferred prettiness. As in this kludge doesn't "fool" Prettier. It's by design.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is months old, but I posted something similar on Prettier's issues and found a better solution. Leaving it here for people who land here by search.

Set the option `--html-whitespace-sensitivity` to `ignore` and you will get your desired output:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="emailRef.hasError('email')">
  A valid email address must be used
</ng-container>
```

---

Although this is not recommended as whitespace formatting can cause issues like extra spacing around text and stuff, which might affect your UI design's consistency.

More info about this here: https://prettier.io/blog/2018/11/07/1.15.0.html#whitespace-sensitive-formatting

---

Thanks to this reply on GitHub: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/9381#issuecomment-707156908

Comment: Now that _is_ interesting. The way it wraps `div` is different from `span` by default, eg, since whitespace won't change the way block elements are displayed, but will for inline like `span` so span gets the gt & lt touching text treatment. "_Instead of breaking your code or just doing nothing, we introduce whitespace-sensitive formatting, which follows the default CSS display value for every element to identify if the whitespace inside it is significant, and wraps the tags in such a way as to avoid adding or removing significant whitespace._" Neat!

Comment: Where I should set this option? Thx