# In Prettier, how do I prevent HTML closing tag's ">" character being placed on a new line?

Tags: vue.js, prettier, prettier-eslint

I am running into a particular problem with [Prettier](https://prettier.io) alongwith Vue.js since a very long time. It seems like there's no solution to this so I am posting a question here as a last resort. This issue happens if your HTML code is nested deep and you have `printWidth` attribute is enabled in Prettier (which is enabled by default).

**Prettier 2.1.2**
[Playground link](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEAeeBbADgGwIbwB8AOlAARmoAmAlgG4nkWW0OnPPX2McddtNenVjyG9UEHKLHicNaTPEAnCAFd4SgLRyoAazJh8AZyMBeYiAAeATwBemw3hNk8AIzAPjRi2RgRzIAD0ABYQGHAWhAASYXCogSrqcFo6ugqKlIFy6Yqo2ewZymoa2jR6Bl4BNvaOzm4etd4gvv4WgVgQRjBNhAAKnd3xiSWpOTLx+YK5gZJjnIEiBULxi1MUK9xLmavrC5tQ8Zi4BHCEIAA0IBBYMDTQRsigeEoqAO69zwgPKHg4r3jWB6XVxKPBgXRwGAAZSwYLKAHNkDAlKo4Jc4BhXHAqFRsQAZPBQeGqPDwuAAMQgSgwBFuROQIDw6ggFxAwRgGBwAHVgjR4EZYWA4FCvnz6HzrAywCZWWUjMkYL1QfCacgAGa-eWXABWRksACFQeDIVC8OE8WU4OrNWiQLrLFCETg4ABFVQQeDWnBakCwpTypQMuio1lYJRlGBcmhUGDBZAADgADJcw504FzQVgGWG4AG6FbLgBHd3wJXXb6MoyaKBwbHY1lKODFmiNpWk1VIDXe23yjA0JEontO10lq2dm2XGBuKMxuNIABMk9BNB08IAwmEOyBcwBWVmqeUAFTc3y7PuDcAAklBcbAoWBwzcAII3qEwazOr3ygC+36AA)

```sh
--parser vue
```

**Input:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <ol>
              <li>
                <router-link class="xyz-class abc-class" to="/home">Home</router-link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <router-link class="xyz-class abc-class" to="/posts">Posts</router-link>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Output:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <ol>
              <li>
                <router-link class="xyz-class abc-class" to="/home"
                  >Home</router-link
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <router-link class="xyz-class abc-class" to="/posts"
                  >Posts</router-link
                >
              </li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Expected behavior:**

Any of these would be fine and neater in my opinion.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <ol>
              <li>
                <router-link class="xyz-class abc-class" to="/home">
                  Home
                </router-link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <router-link class="xyz-class abc-class" to="/posts">
                  Posts
                </router-link>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

OR

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <ol>
              <li>
                <router-link
                  class="xyz-class abc-class"
                  to="/home"
                >Home</router-link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <router-link
                  class="xyz-class abc-class"
                  to="/posts"
                >Posts</router-link>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

Am I missing some option here that I can disable/enable to prevent this? If so, please guide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prettier formatting configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59692928/prettier-formatting-configuration)

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks, the question is about the same but the solution still doesn't fall close.

Answer (score 6):

I've found a solution to this problem. Leaving it here for people who land here by search.

Set the option `--html-whitespace-sensitivity` to `ignore` and you will get this output:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <ol>
              <li>
                <router-link class="xyz-class abc-class" to="/home">
                  Home
                </router-link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <router-link class="xyz-class abc-class" to="/posts">
                  Posts
                </router-link>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

Although this is not recommended as whitespace formatting can cause issues like extra spacing around text and stuff, which might affect your UI design's consistency.

More info about this here: https://prettier.io/blog/2018/11/07/1.15.0.html#whitespace-sensitive-formatting

---

Thanks to this reply on GitHub: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/9381#issuecomment-707156908