# VScode Prettier breaks cite tag - HTML5

Tags: html, formatting, prettier

I've been searching far and wide and have not found a proper solution to configure Prettier to stop breaking certain tags into 2 lines... in my case it's the `<cite>` tag.

Here's an example:

I want it to be

```
<blockquote>
  <cite>Lorem Ipsum</cite>
</blockquote>
```

or

```
<blockquote>
  <cite>
    Lorem Ipsum
  </cite>
</blockquote>
```

But I get this after format

```
<blockquote>
  <p>    
    ...lorem ipsum paragraph words
  <cite
    ><img src="resources/img/customer-2.jpg " />Lorem Ipsum</cite
  >
  </p>
</blockquote>
```

I realize that it's probably longer than 80 hence the break, but I'd prefer if it kept the tag intact. Is there a way to fix this without modifying **Print Width** attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [the prettier docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#jsx-brackets), you should be able to fix this with `"jsxBracketSameLine":true`
in your config or with this flag `--jsx-bracket-same-line` in the command line.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59695635/14492841) to a similar question may also be able to help you

You can also use *whitespace-sensitive formatting* or *magic comments*, as explained [here](https://prettier.io/blog/2018/11/07/1.15.0.html)

> We also allow magic comments (e.g., ) to tell
> Prettier how to format elements due to the fact that CSS display can
> be changed:

```
<!-- input -->
<!-- display: block -->
<span class="dolorum atque aspernatur">Est molestiae sunt facilis qui rem.</span>

<!-- output -->
<!-- display: block -->
<span class="dolorum atque aspernatur">
  Est molestiae sunt facilis qui rem.
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks @PMO1948. This helped me a lot. I can't believe I didn't find that specific config in the docs!